# Android working with views in widget

Tags: android, android-widget

I am trying to make a widget for my app, and I want it to be with a buttonm progress bar and text view, which would later be changed, so I need to somehow work with the views themselves, like I can from an activity, show a view, hide a view, change a button background etc...
I tried tweaking with the sample code from the Android documentations, but I can only start an activity with this

```
public class WidgetProvider extends AppWidgetProvider {

    @Override
    public void onUpdate(Context context, AppWidgetManager appWidgetManager, int[] appWidgetIds) {
        super.onUpdate(context, appWidgetManager, appWidgetIds);
        final int N = appWidgetIds.length;
        for (int i = 0; i < N; i++) {
            int appWidgetId = appWidgetIds[i];
            Intent intent = new Intent(context, ActivityMain.class);
            PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(context, 0, intent, 0);
            RemoteViews views = new RemoteViews(context.getPackageName(), R.layout.widget_layout);          
            views.setOnClickPendingIntent(R.id.sync_button, pendingIntent);
            appWidgetManager.updateAppWidget(appWidgetId, views);
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        super.onReceive(context, intent);
    }

}
```

Does the widget need to be connected to an activity in order to make actions (connect to the internet, write in the database, write in the objects of the apps instance (if there is one))? And can I work with views the way I am asking?

Answer (score 0):

Outside of setting on-click `PendingIntent`s on views, there isn't much you can do inside of a widget. The standard recipe is:

1. Make a `PendingIntent` that sends a broadcast ([`PendingIntent.getBroadcast()`](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/PendingIntent.html#getBroadcast%28android.content.Context,%20int,%20android.content.Intent,%20int%29)) and set it on the appropriate view in your widget.
2. In the `BroadcastReceiver` that receives the intent, you update the widget to show a spinner and start a Service to do whatever long-running work you want to do (e.g connect to the internet).
3. Once that work is done, you can update your widget again and remove the spinner.